# Require once path doesn't set properly

Tags: php, path, directory

When I echo my path:

```
echo __DIR__ . '\..\functions\sanitize.php';
```

I get this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website\php\core\..\functions\sanitize.php
```

But it has to be like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website\php\functions\sanitize.php
```

Why doesn't my path go one step back? It doesn't let me get out of the core folder.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `realpath` function as explained here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use realpath: [see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)